# Shared VPC google cloud insuficient permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to implement shared VPC, but it always returns the message "You don't have the permissions to perform the action on the selected resource."

I own the project and the option "Compute Shared VPC Admin" does not appear in IAM.

Could someone help, please.

Answer (score 0):

"Compute Shared VPC Admin" role can be granted only at the organization level by organization admin [Refer to this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute.xpnAdmin)